# Azure Cognitive Speech TTS API does not work on Windows 8, 8.1, Server 2012, Server 2012R2 since 2022-01

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I found an issue of Azure Cognitive Speech TTS Service;
Azure Cognitive Speech TTS API does not work on Windows 8,/8.1/Server 2012/Server2012R2 since 2022-01.

I made a program with Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK and it worked well on Windows 8/8.1/Server2012/Server2012R2 as well as Windows 10/Server 2019.

I confirmed that there were logs that it has worked correctly until 2021-11-30 at least.
However, it does not work today.

So, I made a simple sample with Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.csharp nuget package.

My sample code is as the following;

```
public static async Task SynthesisToAudioFileAsync(string text, string outputFileName)
{
    var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("xxxxx", "westus2");

    config.SpeechSynthesisLanguage = "ko-KR";
    config.SetSpeechSynthesisOutputFormat(SpeechSynthesisOutputFormat.Audio24Khz48KBitRateMonoMp3);
    config.SpeechSynthesisVoiceName = "ko-KR-SunHiNeural";

    using (var fileOutput = AudioConfig.FromWavFileOutput(outputFileName))
    {
        using (var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(config, fileOutput))
        {
            var result = await synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(text);

            if (result.Reason == ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Speech synthesized to [{outputFileName}]");
            }
            else if (result.Reason == ResultReason.Canceled)
            {
                var cancellation = SpeechSynthesisCancellationDetails.FromResult(result);
                Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={cancellation.Reason}");

                if (cancellation.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={cancellation.ErrorCode}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails=[{cancellation.ErrorDetails}]");
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Did you update the subscription info?");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(result.Reason.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It works well on Windows 10/Server2019 with no error.
However, it does not work on Windows 8,/8.1/Server 2012/Server2012R2.
Of course, I executed windows update fully.

The error message is as the following;

```
CANCELED: Reason=Error
CANCELED: ErrorCode=ConnectionFailure
CANCELED: ErrorDetails=[Connection failed (no connection to the remote host). In
ternal error: 11. Error details: Code: 0. USP state: 2. Received audio size: 0 b
ytes.]
CANCELED: Did you update the subscription info?
```

I suspect that it may be TLS 1.2 issue and tried as the followings;

1. I changed Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.csharp nuget package to several versions - 1.14, 1.13 and 1.19(latest version) but it did not work.
2. I tried to enable TLS 1.2 on Windows 8.1/Server2012 according to many google search results;
   https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/memdocs/blob/main/memdocs/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/includes/update-net-framework-to-support-tls-1-2.md
   https://hide.me/en/knowledgebase/how-to-enable-tls-1-1-tls-1-2-in-windows-7-and-8/
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client

and other many postings.

But, it did not work.

3. I downloaded Cognitive-Speech-TTS sample (Cognitive-Speech-TTS-master.zip) and run C# sample in Old folder.
   https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-TTS

It does not use Azure SDK and implements https rest API in low level. So I can review and change codes.

It also worked on Windows 10 but did not work on Windows 81./Server2012 as the following error message;

```
Starting TTSSample request code execution.

Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> 
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> 
System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context) 
 at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
```

I confirmed that token API (https://westus2.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken) was called well but speak API (https://westus2.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1) was not called with error message.

According to error message, it seems to TLS 1.2 issue.

So, I added to the following line;

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
```

The error message became changed as the following on Windows 10 as well as Windows 8.1/Server2012

```
Starting Authtentication

Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> 
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host ---> 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
```

It was expected behavior because I forced TLS 1.1.
However, the error occurred in authentication step, contrary to above result - above test passed authentication.

So, TLS 1.2 may be enabled on my Windows 81./server2012 because token Uri may require TLS 1.2 according to above testing result.

I tired with speech recognition C# sample in cognitive-services-speech-sdk-master.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk

It worked well Windows 81./Server2012 as well as Windows 10.

MS doc said that Azure Cognitive Service requires TLS 1.2.
If TLS 1.2 is not available on my Windows 8.1/Server2012, all Azure Cognitive Service API must fail.
However, only TTS API fails.
Beside, it has worked until 2021-11 at least.

I've tried almost everything I could, but failed.

Finally I suspect that there may be some changes in Azure Cognitive TTS system at the end of 2021 and it may make the issue related to TLS connection from Windows 8/8.1/Server2012/Server2012R2.

In fact, the issue was reported on my customer's machines and upgrading Windows OS to Windows10/Server2019 is not an option because of many reasons.
So, I have to find a workaround on Windows 8/8.1/Server2012/Server2012R2.

Could you please let me know how I can solve the issue?

Best regards.

P.S.

I captured network packets of Cognitive-Speech-TTS  C# sample using WireShark and confirmed that TLS 1.2 was used.

First handshaking to retrieve token(westus2.api.cognitive.microsoft.com - 20.51.8.244) succeeded but second handshaking to Azure Cognitive TTS Service(westus2.tts.speech.microsoft.com - 20.51.12.193) failed with the following message;

```
TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Handshake Failure).
```

I tested on Windows 10 and all TLS 1.2 handshaking succeeded with same test console program.

I added the following code to ignore certificate validation but it did not work;

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) =>
            {
                return true;
            };
```

Comment: I would use a sniffer like wireshark to see what version of TLS is being used.  The best solution is to use Net 4.7.2 or later which defaults to using TLS in operating system instead of in Net.  Older versions of Net did not support all the encryption modes for TLS.  Then make sure the Server is updated to use TLS 1.2 or 1.3 (SSL, TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 are obsolete).  With TLS there is a certificate block that is sent from server to client with a list of certificates that can be used for the connection. Client then looks up in stores the certificate name.  You will fail if certificate is not found.

Comment: @jdweng I have read postings which you said and tried to change target .NET Framework to 4.8 and remove assigning ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol to use OS default TLS version, and add certificate handler to ignore certificate validation but it did not work too.

I also have suspect certificate issue but certificate issue makes different error message which contains "certificate" text. I have experienced same error message at other project and it resulted from TLS version issue and have solved by settings ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol.

Comment: @jdweng I have the posting realted to Azure Certificate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65582772/certificate-validation-error-when-invoking-azure-cognitive-search-api 

If it is certificate issue, Azure Cognitive speech recognition API must fail, but it worked. Moreover Azure TTS API have worked until end of 2021. I will investigate certificate issue and other TLS issue but I think that it may result from Azure Server, not client side. Thank you for the reply and I will try wireshark.

Comment: I captured network packets using WireShark and confirmed that TLS 1.2 was used.
First handshaking to retrieve token succeeded but second handshaking to Azure Cognitive TTS Service failed with  message - TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Handshake Failure). I tested on Windows 10 and all TLS 1.2 handshaking succeeded with same test console program.

Answer (score 0):

I found actual reason.
It was TLS cipher suite issue of Azure TTS Service API Server.

I executed sslscan to westus2.tts.speech.microsoft.com and the result was as the following;

```
westus2.tts.speech.microsoft.com 
Preferred TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256   Curve 25519 DHE 253 
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384   Curve 25519 DHE 253 
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305   Curve 25519 DHE 253
```

I compared packet capturing result of WireShark between Windows 8.1 and Windows 10.

The result of Windows 10 has ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 and ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 but the result of Windows 8.1 does not.

So, Azure TTS API cannot work on Windows8/8.1/Server2012/Server2012R2 and it must be fixed by MS.

Comment: I think that you can add the cipher suites given this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-8-1 : "Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 are updated by Windows Update by the update 2919355 applied which adds the new cipher suites and changes the priority order"

Comment: Related KB2919355 for Windows Server 2012 R2 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42334, and for Windows 8.1: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42327

Comment: I applied all windows update and confirmed that KB2919355 was already installed, but the issue occurred.

I found same issue posting - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/103288/azure-text-to-speech-is-not-accessable-in-windows.html?childToView=705574#answer-705574

Comment: I read following documents and confirmed that ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 and ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 were not found in windows 8.1.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-8-1
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-10-v1903

Comment: I found a bug report in azure github and MS is working on a fix.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/1362

Comment: Good investigation (and efforts were already made when you post the question, thanks for that). Don't hesitate to edit your question to add what you found, if other people face the same issue